# Optimizing the openpyxl program

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, excel

**Purpose of the code:**

Let's say I have 3 excel files to deal with.

Those file have already been filtered or hidden because the content is very large. And I only need part of the content for every excel files.

I don't want to open every file and worksheets in order to copy the desired range.

I want to write a code to combine every filtered or hidden cells and put those cells to a brand new workbook.

**Steps of the code:**

1.Combine every filtered or hidden cells of all worksheets for every excel files.

2.Create a new empty single-worksheet workbook.

3.Put all cells of Step 1 into Step 2.

**Problem of the code:**

1.Running too slow. Maybe there are too many `for` loops?

```
import openpyxl
import os
import glob


path = os.getcwd()
data=[]
x=input('name：') + '.xlsx'
target_xls = os.path.join(path,x)
for file in glob.glob(path+'\*.*'):
    if file.endswith((".xlsx")):
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file, data_only=True)
        for sheet in wb.worksheets:
            for j in range(2, sheet.max_row+1 ):
                for i in range(1,sheet.max_column+1):
                    ihidden = sheet.row_dimensions[j].hidden  # Row Visibility True / False
                    svalue = sheet.cell(column=i,row=j).value
                    if ihidden == True:
                        shidden = "HIDDEN"
                    else:
                        shidden = "VISIBLE"
                        data.append(svalue)
WP= openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = WP.active
ws.title = "Sheet1"
x=sheet.max_column
new_list = [data[i:i+x] for i in range(0, len(data), x)]
for elem in new_list:
    ws.append(elem)
WP.save(target_xls)
```

Comment: I do have a deja vú it seems. Didnt you ask that a few hours before? Please be patient about getting answers here.